# Assigning links to multiselect fields does not work

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, storage, multi-select

So lately i started working with Wordpress and found a plugin which stores certain input values in a database. This storing has many options and one of them is storing multiselect fields (option A, B or both - or more options if you would like).

Though, i wanted to adjust this multiselect storing a bit by also giving the stored values (which are obviously pre defined) a certain link, like lets say: Option A gets link X while option B gets link XX. These link are not active when the person uploads the information (putting it in the database) but they are visible once you show the information (that is stored in the database - so when you retrieve the data). To get this working i came up with the following piece of code:

```
    <?php while( $this->have_fields() ) : $this->the_field(); // each field is one cell ?>
      <td class="<?php echo $this->field->name ?>-field">
        <?php
if(!function_exists("value_link")) {
function value_link($value) {
  $map = array(
    'Yes' => 'http://www.google.com',
    'No' => 'http://www.hotmail.com'
  );
  return $map[$value];
}
}

if ($this->field->name === 'edit_link') {
  $output = '';
  $value_array = explode(',', (string) $this->field->value);
  foreach ((array)$value_array as $the_value) {
    $the_value = trim($the_value); // in case there are spaces
    $output .= '<a href="' . value_link($the_value) . '">' . $the_value . '</a> ';
  }
  echo $output;
} else {
  $this->field->print_value();
}
?>
      </td>
  <?php endwhile; // each field ?>
  </tr>
<?php endwhile; // each record ?>
</tbody>
```

A bit of explaining;
The first few code lines are standard which just echo's the table fields in which the data is shown. The related question code starts at the first IF function where i am setting the links to the 2 multiselect options i created.

The next IF statement returns the one field which is related to the multiselect (so the frontend column in which the data input (multiselect input) is shown. Well and the rest in that IF statement speaks for itself, it should get the multiselect data that is uploaded and give the proper link to it.

Though, for some reason, the $output only outputs (echo's) the word: Array. This is clickable (as in, its linked) but when i click it, it redirects me to nothing, well, it redirects me to the same page instead of the above defined links. Besides that, when the uploaded data is both the options, it still only shows ONE array word instead of 2.

So summarized:

1. It only shows the word Array instead of the Yes or No option/value
2. The word has a link but doesn't redirect me to the defined links
3. It only shows ONE Array word while the data should have 2 Array words (when i have uploaded both the Yes and NO)

Anyone knows what causes this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try -_- + ^^

Maybe that will solve the PHP redirector to your datastore array.